# JBoss Logging ignores "org.jboss.logging.provider" system property

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-logging

I'm trying to set jboss-logging (3.1.0.GA) to use log4j (1.2.17) through the system property `-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=log4j` but it's not working, it always use jboss logger (jboss-7.2.0).